# How to share a Linux directory as a folder in Windows?

Tags: mount, samba, sshfs

Maybe it seems that the best way is using samba. But it's not ideal. Access to some files or directories will not be possible unless changing the file or directory's owner or mode. For example, one may not edit a file owned by a normal user (not root) or the file mode is 644.

For this, I decided to mount a linux directory by ssh protocol. For this, I used SFTP Net Drive which seems to be a better choice between some other mounters. But it doesn't work as it should. Payment is required for some other software like ExpanDrive. winsshfs seems to be discontinued and is not bugless as this.

Anyway, I like to know whether there's a better software to be free and work without any problem with ssh, OR may I use another protocol for this purpose?

Comment: "Access to some files or directories will not be possible unless changing the file or directory's owner or mode." – **The whole point of having ownership and permissions is to restrict access in some circumstances.** Samba is rather rich in options to translate between Windows and Unix scheme ([here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html),[there](https://askubuntu.com/q/269643/693277)); so I don't really get what the problem is. Besides, seeking product or service recommendations is off-topic here on Super User. You may want to rephrase the question.

Comment: The problem is that with the same owner I'll encounter problem accessing files and folders via samba. eg. I may access them from inside Linux shell and I can't via samba with the same user.

Comment: Isn't this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? The right solution may be fixing your Samba configuration. For now we know nothing about it so we cannot help. You can ask a separate question or even [edit] this one and completely change its topic (as long as there are no answers).